# Zoom variable or pixel distance

Tags: leaflet, distance, carto, zoom

I have query by distance working in a framework that generates a list of features within a fixed distance of a clicked feature. I would like to make the queried distance variable based on either:

Pixel Distance from clicked feature (something like):

```
select cartodb_id, label, title from full_list where st_distance( the_geom, st_GeomFromText('POINT("+lon+" "+lat+")', 4326), true ) < ("+pixels+")
```

Or current zoom level-based resolution (something like):

```
select cartodb_id, label, title from full_list where st_distance( the_geom, st_GeomFromText('POINT("+lon+" "+lat+")', 4326), true ) < (SELECT CDB_XYZ_Resolution("+zoom+"))
```

I wonder if this is possible. Here is the jsbin wherein CDB_XYZ_Resolution uses a fixed zoom variable: http://jsbin.com/vifaleri/1/edit

To update the distance variable when a feature is clicked, I'm not quite sure where to include something like this:

```
map.on('zoomend', function(){
    var zoom = map.getZoom();
    console.log(zoom);
  });
```

to be reachable by the `CDB_XYZ_Resolution("+zoom+")` part of the feature click query.

Thanks and apologies for my ignorance. If grids are the solution, I have been unable to implement grid queries of points in the same cell as the selected point. I've tried this, among other similar grid queries that return no records:

```
WITH hgrid AS (SELECT CDB_HexagonGrid(ST_Expand(!bbox!, greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 15), greatest(!pixel_width!,!pixel_height!) * 15) as cell) SELECT hgrid.cell as the_geom_webmercator, 1 as cartodb_id, count(i.cartodb_id) as point_count FROM hgrid, full_list i WHERE i.cartodb = "+data.cartodb_id+" AND ST_Intersects(hgrid.cell, i.the_geom_webmercator)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think I got it: After `map.setView` I put `var zoom = map.getZoom(zoom); console.log(zoom);` and used `(SELECT CDB_XYZ_Resolution("+zoom+")*(("+zoom+")+1))` for the distance.

Comment: Great. What are you trying to achieve exactly?

Comment: Query by distance where the distance is in pixels, dynamically adjusted at zoom: helps list coincident points. Got it working here: http://pu.bli.sh/maps/web_map/bennioncenter/index.html.

Answer (score 1):

First, one logs the zoom after the click query:

`var zoom = map.getZoom(zoom);
console.log(zoom);`

Then one changes the sql to:
`SELECT cartodb_id, label FROM table_name where ST_Distance(the_geom, st_GeomFromText('POINT("+lon+" "+lat+")', 4326), true ) < (SELECT CDB_XYZ_Resolution("+zoom+")*(("+zoom+")*1.75)) ORDER BY label`

The number 1.75 is the resolution multiplier. See https://github.com/CartoDB/cartodb-postgresql/wiki/CDB_XYZ_Resolution

And a working example on github: https://github.com/tbushman/emergencyservices